# Button hover is not working in Tab widget with vertical layout in QT

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, interface, hover

I am working on GUI application in QT C++. I have a form with grid layout. One of the cell of grid filled with tab widget with some buttons, combo box and text boxes. All the widget in this tab are not working with mouse hover effect. I am using style sheet, I applied it one centeralwidget stylesheet and also for individual widgets to further verify but it is still not working. If I place button in grid other than tab than hover effect are working on that grid button but still not on tab button.

```
QPushButton:hover { background-color: #66c011; }
```

Other than hover like changing color, backgroundcolor and font are working fine.

How this can be fixed. Any help will be appreciated.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem as follow.

1. I removed all the styles related to pushbutton from all widgets i.e. mainWindow, pushbutton, centerWidget etc.
2. Put the style `QPushButton { background-color: #ffc000; }` and `QPushButton:hover { background-color: #66c011; }` in the tabWidget (instance of tab on which you are working)

It worked as perfect.

Good Luck everyone